# LiveTile for Win8.1 Not Working When Purchased from Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, live-tile, win-universal-app

When I deploy my app SecretSanta from the Store the LiveTile does not work. It also does not work if I deploy the app as a sideload.

The LiveTile does work if I deploy using Visual Studio (Debug or Release Mode).

How can I debug this? How can I figure out what the issue is? Does anyone already know what the issue is?

UPDATE: I have a theory this has to do with images not deploying correctly. Thoughts?

Comment: You might want to include a code snippet so we know what type of content you're trying to show and how.